# Outputting values from MySQL into a preformatted table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a periodic table and am new to php. I have looked far and wide for information on how to accomplish this task, but I can't find anything. What I want to do is query my database and get values for things like atomic weight, name, element symbol, etc, and have them populate in my periodic table that I have constructed with html and css. However, I just don't know to run the "while" loop and have the data populate in the appropriate spaces. I understand how to create a table with the results, but I don't understand how to have results populate into an html structure that has already been created. Here is a part of my code. Again, I am very new to php, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly certain this has a lot to do with where I'm placing my opening/closing php tags. Essentially, how do I get the loop to recognize the variables within the html? Do I close php tags and reopen?

Thank you tremendously.

```
   <?php
//query database (connection successful)//
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementdata", $link);


    //fetch results into array to loop through//
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {



//begin table structure where I would like to insert data//
<div id="hydrogen" class="element group1 period1">
    <span class="number"> echo $row['atomicNumber']; </span><br>
    <span class="symbol">H</span><br>
    <span class="name"> echo $row['name']; </span><br>
    <span class="molmass">1.007&nbsp;94</span></div>

<div id="Helium" class="element group18 period1">
     <span class="number">echo $row['atomicNumber'];</span><br>
    <span class="symbol">He</span><br>
    <span class="name"> echo $row['name']; </span><br>
    <span class="molmass">4.002&nbsp;602</span></div> 
//...table continues...//

?>
```

Comment: How do you know that the query will return the items in the order you are printing them? In other words, how do you know that `$row['atomicNumber']` will be correect for Hydrogen?

Comment: Burhan is right, i have written my code to make it independent of the order MySQL returns it, you should be fine as long as the group and period classes work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i am not sure about whether you are storing the molmass,symbol,group and period in the MySQL table, but you most probably are. Since i dont know what you named them, please replace molmass,atomicSymbol,atomic_group and atomic_period with your coloumn name.

You can use this code,

```
    <?php
//query database (connection successful)//
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementdata", $link);
//fetch results into array to loop through//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // echo the first line, i.e the div
    echo "<div id='{$row['name']}' class='element {$row['atomic_group']} {$row['atomic_period']}'>";
    // Echo the atomic number, symbol, name and molmass
    echo "<span class='number'>{$row['atomicNumber']}</span><br>";
    echo "<span class='symbol'>{$row['atomicSymbol']}</span><br>";
    echo "<span class='name'>{$row['name']}</span><br>";
    echo "<span class='molmass'>{$row['molmass']}</span><br>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Explaination: The {} is required for us to insert the $row[''] syntax in a string, else it gives us trouble.

Rest we just loop over everything in the table, fetch what you named them and what group and period they belong to, create a div. Then we print each of their properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with two approaches, using PHP to echo the HTML or having PHP in the HTML.

**PHP printing HTML**

```
<?php
//query database (connection successful)//
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementdata", $link);


//fetch results into array to loop through//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    //begin table structure where I would like to insert data//
    echo '<div id="hydrogen" class="element group1 period1">';
    echo '    <span class="number">' . $row['atomicNumber'] . '</span><br>';
    echo '    <span class="symbol">H</span><br>';
    echo '    <span class="name">' . $row['name'] . '</span><br>';
    echo '    <span class="molmass">1.007&nbsp;94</span></div>';
}
```

**HTML with PHP**

```
<?php
//query database (connection successful)//
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementdata", $link);


//fetch results into array to loop through//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    //begin table structure where I would like to insert data//
    <div id="hydrogen" class="element group1 period1">';
        <span class="number"><?php echo $row['atomicNumber']; ?></span><br>';
        <span class="symbol">H</span><br>';
        <span class="name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><br>';
        <span class="molmass">1.007&nbsp;94</span></div>';
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to step in and out of PHP

After :

```
//fetch results into array to loop through//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

If you want to output HTML, you must close PHP

```
?>
```

Now when you want to output some PHP variable inside a HTML tag :

```
<span class="number"><?php echo $row['atomicNumber']; ?></span><br>
```

Similar to the opening and closing tags in HTML, you enclose your PHP code within PHP tags.

Answer (score -1):

Well, let's try one possible way:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

open your db stuff

$query = " SELECT name,
                  symbol,
                  atomicnumber,
                  molmass,
                  otherstuff
           FROM periodictabletable
           WHERE index > 0 ";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database");

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['symbol']."</td><td>".$row['atomicnumber']."</td><td>".$row['molmass']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you get this up and running, you can embed all kinds of formatting tags into the html, just make sure you only use single quotes for stuff like - class='numbercolor' .

But there are many ways to do this. You could make the table in html, then populate it with an ajax call - depends on what you want to do.
Have fun!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. I think I know what I need to do now. Stackoverflow is a wonderful resource, and I appreciate your time.